# NumPy/Scikit on Ubuntu, better built from source of precompiled (e.g. Anaconda)?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Different documents provide contradictory information whether it is better to install NumPy with pip (from my experience `pip install numpy` on Ubuntu always builds NumPy from source) or to use a compiled distribution, for example `Anaconda2`.

Website [SciPy.org - Building From Source on Linux](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/linux.html) states that:

> (...) if you want to use the last improvements done to NumPy and SciPy
>   on Linux, you have to build it from sources.

While [Scikit-learn.org - Installing scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) explains:

> We don’t recommend installing scipy or numpy using pip on linux, as
>   this will involve a lengthy build-process with many dependencies.
>   Without careful configuration, building numpy yourself can lead to an
>   installation that is much slower than it should be.

Which way is better for performance of programs which deal with big data and do machine learning, when run on `Ubuntu 14.04` ?

Comment: If you downvote, I'd appreciate a short comment explaining how I can improve quality of this SO question or what to avoid next time. Thanks!

Comment: `Which way is better for performance of programs` - if you know what you are doing, compiling yourself is always as least as good as a binary version. Normal users like you and me usually do not care about the tiny extra percents of performance though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paper [Lund et al., Doubling the Performance of Python/NumPy with less than 100 SLOC](http://curis.ku.dk/ws/files/126010515/Doubling.pdf) describes how small changes to code and gcc/kernel environment make for major improvements of NumPy performance. Therefore, I'd like to close this question with conclusion:

- use compiled distribution of NumPy/Scipy library whenever possible
- compile NumPy/Scipy if you have no other choice or you want to customize build parameters because you know what you are doing

Discussion on the matter is welcome so I can change my answer